# Как узнать какой класс не зарегистрирован? Ошибка в Visual Basic 80040154

Tags: excel, vba, visual-basic, opc

В файле Excel Имеется скрипт VB который исправно работал и до сих пор работает на всех остальных комппьютерах. Но недавно я переустановил и OPC сервер, и Microsift Office. После этого начала вылезать ошибка 80040154

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В интернете перерыл около 100 статей, в которых говорится всё сводится к тому, чтобы переустановить программу. В итоге я несколько раз переустановил Office и OPC сервер, но ошибка по прежнему вылезает. 
Нашёл очень полезную [статью на Хабре](https://habr.com/en/sandbox/33155/) по этой ошибке, но там была проблема с Windows Installer, и как эту статью применить я не знаю.
При нажатии на кнопку Debug на перемещает к ошибочной стороке кода
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я понимаю, что мне необходимо зарегистрировать класс, но не понимаю как мне выяснить какой класс регистрировать?
Прошу помощи, если кто то решал такую проблему, дайте пожалуйста совет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном случае проблема рещилась переустановкой microsoft office с 64-битной версии на 32 битную версию. Надеюсь кому-нибудь это поможет